# Hide field in xpath exp odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

What is the best solution to hide field eg. partner_id in

```xml
<xpath expr=".">
        <field name="partner_id" />
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="attributes">
       <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the best way of hiding any field from the view.

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way with more details to make field *invisible*, *readonly* etc at once based on specific condition.

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('field_name', 'Operator', Value)], 
                             'readonly': [('field_name', 'Operator', Value)]}
    </attribute>
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way which you can implement is

```xml
<field name="partner_id" position="replace">
    <field name="partner_id" invisible="1" />
</field>
```

This is just an alternate of above solutions.